# In Java, how I download a page that was redirected?

Tags: java

I making a web crawler and there are some pages that redirect to other. How I get the page that the original page redirected?

In some sites like xtema.com.br, I can get the url of redirection using the HttpURLConnection class with the getHeaderField("Location") method, but in others like visa.com.br, the redirection is made using javascript or another way and this method returns null.

There is some way to always get the page and the url resulting of redirection? The original page without the redirection is not important.

Thanks, and sorry for bad english.

EDIT: Using httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true) to follow the redirections and returning the URL with httpConn.getURL worked, but I have two issues.

1: The httpConn.getURL only will return the actual url of the redirected page if I call httpConn.getDate before. If I dont this, it will return the original URL before the redirections.

2: Some sites like visa.com.br get the answer 200, but if I open then in the web browser,  I see another page. 
Eg.: my program - visa.com.br - answer 200 (no redirections)
web broser - visa.com.br/go/principal.aspx - html code different of the version that i get in my program

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `HttpURLConnection`, it follows redirects by default.

In case you want to see the redirected URL, you'll have to do:

```
httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
httpConn.connect(); 
int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
while ((responseCode / 100) == 3) { /* codes 3XX are redirections */
   String newLocationHeader = httpConn.getHeaderField( "Location" );
   /* open a new connection and get the content for the URL newLocationHeader */
   /* ... */
   responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
   /* do it until you get some code that is not a redirection */
}
```

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks. I expressed wrong one thing. I need to get the URL of the redirection too. It's in the HttpURLConnection, right? Which is the method to get it?

Comment: See the new edition of the answer. In this case is a bit more complicated.

Comment: I need test the code in the edition first, but I was doing similar code and happens that not all sites that returns the new url. In some the value returned from the getHeaderField is null. Anyway I need to test the code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I tested the code. A "rollback". in the answer is better. Let the HttpURLConnection follow the redirections with the httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false ); and so return the url with httpConn.getURL method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily get javascript redirection. And HTTP redirection is handled by default by the `HttpURLConnection`. What you can do is, search the page contents for several keywords:

- the [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) tag
- `document.location=`, `window.location=` and both with `.href=`

But this does not guarantee anything. People might be calling javascript functions from external js files and you will pretty much need to fetch resources and parse javascript, which you aren't willing to do, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [Apache's HTTP client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/).  Just another option.